# Firebase Dynamic Link doesn't redirect to the app when open through Chrome

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, android-deep-link

Firebase Dynamic Link doesn't redirect to the app when open through Chrome, Where if I'm using any other browser, it's redirecting to the app.
So the question is , Chrome is using what's differ than other or What is the solution in our code level ,when creating Dynamic links in our android studio

if I'm using any other browser, it's redirecting to the app.
So the question is , Chrome is using what's differ than other or What is the solution in our code level ,when creating Dynamic links in our android studio

Answer (score 0):

If you are pasting a short link onto Chrome’s address bar, this is an intended behavior where you will be directed to either App Store (iOS) or Play Store (Android) regardless whether the app is installed or not. The original link will not be preserved upon installing or switching to the application. This is because Chrome does not support intent redirection and the browser will only act as a proxy.